# Understanding the return value of MemoryMarshal.Cast

Tags: c#, arrays, marshalling

I'm trying to understand the new C# type `Span<T>`

When reading the Microsoft's article [All About Span: Exploring a New .NET Mainstay](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2017/connect/csharp-all-about-span-exploring-a-new-net-mainstay#what-is-spant) I saw at the bottom of the `What Is Span<T>?` section

> Spans provide a multitude of benefits beyond those already mentioned. For example, spans support the notion of reinterpret casts, meaning you can cast a `Span<byte>` to be a `Span<int>` (where the 0th index into the `Span<int>` maps to the first four bytes of the `Span<byte>`). That way if you read a buffer of bytes, you can pass it off to methods that operate on grouped bytes as ints safely and efficiently.

They don't provide any example in this article but I eventually found the (new way) of doing this in [Adam Storr's article](https://adamstorr.azurewebsites.net/blog/span-t-byte-int-conversions-update) by using the `MemoryMarshal.Cast` method

However when I try to do this, I get a weird result

```cs
var byteArray = new byte[] { 1,0,0,0, 0,1,0,0};
Span<byte> byteSpan = byteArray;
Span<int> intSpan = MemoryMarshal.Cast<byte, int>(byteSpan);
```

Microsoft's articles says `the 0th index into the Span maps to the first four bytes of the Span`. So by creating an array of 8 bytes I get a Span of 2 integers.

The value of the first integer is `1` which is what I was expecting (`0001`) but the for 2nd integer I get the value `256` which is what I don't understand.

Am I not supposed to get the value `2` because the 2nd half of my bytes array is `0010`?

Comment: Bytes aren't bits. On a little-endian machine, the bytes 00-01-00-00 represent the integer 0x00000100, which is 256.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. However now I'm really confused why the first half of my array `1,0,0,0` is worth `1` in decimal instead of 4096. I don't understand canton7's answer

Comment: [Little-endian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) -- the bytes are stored with the lowest significant bits (hence also bytes) first. 01-00-00-00 is the integer 0x00000001, which is 1. 4096 would be 0-16-0-0 (decimal) or 0x00-0x10-0x00-00 (hex), giving the integer 0x00001000. You're much better off thinking in bytes than in bits here, as the machine also treats bytes as one single entity (the "order" of the bits *within* the byte is essentially invisible and we conventionally always write the most significant bits first regardless of endianness).

Comment: "I don't understand canton7's answer" -- because each time you made a claim about what he said, it was different from what he actually said. There's a trick to understanding such answers, which is to empty your head of all beliefs and assumptions, start from a blank slate, and put on it only what's in the answer. For example, you repeatedly mentioned 4096, but 4096 appears nowhere in his answer ... it's what you were expecting, but your expectations were quite wrong.

Answer (score 7):

The number:

```
1
```

(which can be written in hex as):

```
0x00000001
0x0001
0x01
```

Has the big-endian byte pattern:

```
0x00 0x00 0x00 0x01
```

And the little-endian byte pattern:

```
0x01 0x00 0x00 0x00
```

---

The number:

```
256
```

(which can be written in hex as):

```
0x00000100
0x0100
```

Has the big-endian byte pattern:

```
0x00 0x00 0x01 0x00
```

And the little-endian byte pattern:

```
0x00 0x01 0x00 0x00
```

---

Since your machine is little-endian, the `MemoryMarshal.Cast` is using the little-endian representations of numbers. Therefore `1 0 0 0` gets interpreted as `1`, and `0 1 0 0` gets interpreted as `256`.

Comment: In that case the first half of my byte array `1 0 0 0` would be interpreted as `0x1000` right? Which is actually `4096` in decimal but the value of `intSpan[0]` is `1`. Could you please explain me that? I'm confused now. Thanks

Comment: @JérômeMEVEL It's little-endian. The integer value 1 has the bytes `0x00 0x00 0x00 0x01` in big-endian order, or `0x01 0x00 0x00 0x00` in little-endian order

Comment: I'm even more lost now. Why do you interpret `0,1,0,0` as `0x0100` but for `1,0,0,0` you interpret it the other way as `0x0001`?

Comment: @JérômeMEVEL If you don't know what endianness is, please read up on it now. The integer 1 has the hex value `0x00000001` (which you can shorten to `0x0001` or `0x01`, etc). It has the bytes in big-endian order of `0x00 0x00 0x00 0x01`, and in little-endian order of `0x01 0x00 0x00 0x00`. See how the little-endian order is the opposite of the big-endian order? The integer `256` has the hex value `0x00000100` (which you can shorten to `0x0100`). It has the bytes in big-endian order of `0x00 0x00 0x01 0x00`, or in little-endian order of `0x00 0x01 0x00 0x00`.

Comment: I'm reading about endianness since you mentioned it in your answer however I still don't understand why on my little-endian machine the value of `intSpan[0]` is `1`. `0x1000` is `4096` on a little-endian machine. For some reason you seem to treat `1,0,0,0` in big-endian but `0,1,0,0` in little endian. Why???

Comment: @JérômeMEVEL I explained in my previous comment. The little-endian byte pattern `1 0 0 0` has the hex value `0x00000001`, which is the integer 1. The little-endian byte pattern `0 1 0 0` has the hex value `0x00000100`, which is the integer 256. Notice how, with little-endian, the **least-significant** byte comes **first**. I have always treated `1 0 0 0` as little-endian.

Comment: @JérômeMEVEL "In that case the first half of my byte array 1 0 0 0 would be interpreted as 0x1000 right?" No, not right ... **read** the answer, which states that the little-endian byte pattern "0x01 0x00 0x00 0x00" has the value of 1. It's equivalent to `(0x01 >> 3*8) + (0x00 >> 2*8) + (0x00 >> 1*8) + (0x00 >> 0*8)` ... which is 1.

Comment: @JérômeMEVEL "0x1000 is 4096 on a little-endian machine." But you don't have 0x1000, you have { 1,0,0,0 }, which is 4096 on a **big-endian** machine but 1 on a **little-endian** machine.

Comment: @JérômeMEVEL "Why do you interpret 0,1,0,0 as 0x0100 but for 1,0,0,0 you interpret it the other way as 0x0001?" That's not the other way around ... in both cases ss,tt,uu,vv is interpreted as 0xvvuuttss on a little-endian machine (and 0xssttuuvv on a big-endian machine). Perhaps you have confused bytes with nibbles.

Comment: " For some reason you seem to treat 1,0,0,0 in big-endian but 0,1,0,0 in little endian. Why???" -- Because he didn't do that at all ... 1,0,0,0 and 0,1,0,0 both occur in his answer only as little-endian patterns, with the values 1 and 256 respectively.

Comment: @JimBalter This question is 3.5 years old... I doubt this is a problem for them any more!

Comment: There's a good chance that he still doesn't understand endianness. But it's irrelevant ... other people could come here and be similarly confused. SO is a knowledge repository; answers aren't just for the person who asked the question.